# How do I set the weights of an Unscented Kalman Filter?

Tags: localization, kalman-filter

In most of the papers I have read, calculation of weights is done by the following formula:

[image]

Where L is the dimensionality of my state and lambda is calculated by:

[image]

And the usual values for alpha, beta and kappa are given as 0.001, 2 (for Gaussian distributions) and 0 respectively.

My problem is that this would give a value of Lambda that is very close to - L, which drives the weights to huge negative values. This is affecting my covariance estimation, leading to wildly inaccurate predictions. This seems like a fundamental error in the way the weights are calculated, but I'm not sure if I'm missing some critical intuition here.

Comment: I usually set alpha around .8

Comment: I believe kappa is usually set to 3-L

Comment: What dynamics are you using? Is there a toy problem you're working with?

Comment: @holmeski, I am trying to predict the future motion of a body using noisy GPS measurements. Is there a basis for setting kappa? A lot of the sources I saw said a good default is 0

Comment: I was looking at the book Kalman Filtering and Neural Networks which cites A New Approach for Filtering Nonlinear Systems

Comment: can you post the prediction dynamics you are working with?

Comment: Can you post an example of the problem you are seeing? What do the covariances look like?

Comment: @holmeski Plots of a random test case I am using: https://drive.google.com/open?id=13bX0R1ep-DvpGKE13Qr1a1B0hnc1mRAe. This is for 3D position and velocity of a body moving with an initial position and velocity and a constant acceleration. I am checking the estimates for position along x in these plots, with the assumption that if this is right, the remaining estimates will be right too.